# 403 forbidden : You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server Port 443

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I'm trying to run my instance on https and it is throwing this error.

It is working fine on http if I remove the SSL.

This is the message I'm getting on my `error.log`:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/readingroots/
 AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/readingroots/favicon.ico, referer: https://readingroots.in/
```

This is my `000-default.conf` file congif:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@djangoproject.localhost
        ServerName readingroots.in
        ServerAlias www.readingroots.in
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/readingroots
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        Alias /static /home/ubuntu/readingroots/static
<Directory /home/ubuntu/readingroots/static>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ubuntu/readingroots/readbus_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess readingroots python-path=/home/ubuntu/readingroots python-home=/home/ubuntu/readingroots/myprojectenv
        WSGIProcessGroup readingroots
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/readingroots/readbus_project/wsgi.py

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.readingroots.in [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =readingroots.in
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my `000-default-le-ssl.conf` conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@djangoproject.localhost
        ServerName readingroots.in
        ServerAlias www.readingroots.in
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/readingroots
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        Alias /static /home/ubuntu/readingroots/static
<Directory /home/ubuntu/readingroots/static>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ubuntu/readingroots/readbus_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/readingroots.in/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/readingroots.in/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I've tried various things but nothing seems to be working.
Please help and let me know if I can try anything.

Edit:

This is the output after running `ls -l /home/ubuntu/readingroots` command:

```
total 2164
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 26 18:23 actions
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 26 18:23 books
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu     16384 Aug 14 05:32 celerybeat-schedule
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 26 18:23 chats
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu www-data 2120704 Aug 17 23:07 db.sqlite3
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu     18446 Jul 15 19:21 edits.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu       656 Apr 26  2020 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 24 03:20 media
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 24 06:05 myprojectenv
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 26 18:24 pages
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu www-data    4096 Jul 26 05:22 readbus_project
drwxrwxr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 26 18:40 static
drwxrwxr-x 7 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 26 18:38 static2
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 24 03:23 supervisor
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 24 03:23 templates
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jul 26 18:24 users
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root           0 Aug  5 05:43 vi
```

Comment: Does the user id for apache (typically `www-data`) have read access to the directory `/home/ubuntu/readingroots/` and all its sub-contents?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Yes I believe so. How can I confirm?

Comment: Run `ls -l /home/ubuntu/readingroots` to get the file permissions and please add the output to your question

Comment: @Jacob Ran the command, updated the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are using python wsgi and you didn't give it the server permissions on the root node of the project

> error from comments
>
> `[autoindex:error] [pid 27528:tid 140136830449408] [client 103.119.165.25:64522] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/ubuntu/readingroots/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

For your case:
this error in comments means your server can't see wsgi on port 433

In you config there is no `WSGIScriptAlias`, `WSGIDaemonProcess` or any of that for 433 conf..

it should be configured properly in 433 server config as well as 80

---

For others who may counter this issue could help also:

DocumentRoot `/home/ubuntu/readingroots` has no `<Directory>` mark itself so you need to make sure it exists

some thing like this:

```sh
<Directory /home/ubuntu/readingroots>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

---

This issue could appear if the wsgi server itself tries to fetch a file that belongs to other user than the one running the worker, so you need to fix any permission issue

- go to the apache2 config dir `/etc/apache2` on ubuntu - you'll find a file called `magicvars`
- change the `apache-run-user` & `apache-run-group` to what you use in your wsgi service
- give that user and group all permisions on your root Dir

  ```sh
  chown -R user:group *
  ```
- add write premisions to the group members if you use other user than your editing one

  ```sh
  chmod g+x *
  // or
  chmod 774 *
  ```
- add your user to that group if you aren't

  ```
  sudo usermod -a -G group user
  ```

---

> I would recomend "NGNIX" as a proxy for wsgi python applications as I tried both and belive that apache2 is not a good friend of python

Comment: Hi, I've added the permission for '/home/ubuntu/readingroots'. I'm still getting the same error on the UI. While I'm getting this error on the log: `[autoindex:error] [pid 27528:tid 140136830449408] [client 103.119.165.25:64522] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/ubuntu/readingroots/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`
Any idea about it?

Comment: I also checked the permission on apache user and group, it is `www-data` and I think it has all the necessary permission.Is there anything we need to do on `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file?

Comment: this error means your server can't see wsgi on port 433, I re-checked config and found no `WSGIScriptAlias`, `WSGIDaemonProcess` or any of that.. didn't you configure it

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot Sharaf, it worked! I actually had kept `WSGIScriptAlias`, and `WSGIDaemonProcess` in the config for port 443 as well but was getting error for duplicate names. So commented it out, now I tried and changed it to a different one and it worked!!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `Require all granted` option on directories

> /home/ubuntu/readingroots/readbus_project

and

> /home/ubuntu/readingroots/static

whereas you also need a directive for the /home/ubuntu/readingroots directory itself. More [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require).